# How to make meteor work with google apis?

Tags: meteor, google-api, gmail-api, meteor-accounts

please help me to make google apis and meteor work. So I set up accounts-ui accounts-password accounts-google. I took the needed scopes with my accounts-config.js

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

Accounts.ui.config({requestPermissions: {
  google: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing'
  ]
},
  requestOfflineToken: {
    google: true
  }
})
```

On my server I have a method like this

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // Meteor.call('createDraft')


  Meteor.methods({
    'createDraft': function () {
      console.log(this.userId)

      const user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId)
      const email = user.services.google.email
      console.log(email)

      const dataObject = {
        'message': {
          'raw': CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('Hello, World!'))
        }
      }
      HTTP.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/' + encodeURIComponent(email) + '/drafts', dataObject, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('err', error)
        }
        if (result) {
          console.log('res', result)
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

On the client I have a component like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Test extends Component {
  createDraftClick () {
    Meteor.call('createDraft', () => console.log('called createDraft'))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.createDraftClick.bind(this)}>Create Draft</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Test
```

When I click on it and my method is called I get the following response

```
err { [Error: failed [401] {  "error": {   "errors": [    {     "domain": "global",     "reason": "required",     "message": "Login Required",     "locationType": "header",     "location": "Authorization"    }   ],   "code": 401,   "message": "Login Required"  } } ]
I20161219-17:02:07.904(4)?   response: 
I20161219-17:02:07.904(4)?    { statusCode: 401,
I20161219-17:02:07.905(4)?      content: '{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "required",\n    "message": "Login Required",\n    "locationType": "header",\n    "location": "Authorization"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 401,\n  "message": "Login Required"\n }\n}\n',
I20161219-17:02:07.907(4)?      headers: 
I20161219-17:02:07.908(4)?       { 'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UrTNWqenpV_aT_KKab8HA71eHYdc3t8pjIzo6e_JyW4OWz3fIopa6hVpCmDK5nTM0VE8z3UOam8bSNKQNatKjLHHN_zNPFLQl_9eet8VNXO-3yNBYU',
I20161219-17:02:07.908(4)?         vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
I20161219-17:02:07.913(4)?         'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"',
I20161219-17:02:07.914(4)?         'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
I20161219-17:02:07.914(4)?         'content-length': '238',
I20161219-17:02:07.916(4)?         date: 'Mon, 19 Dec 2016 13:02:07 GMT',
I20161219-17:02:07.917(4)?         server: 'UploadServer',
I20161219-17:02:07.917(4)?         'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"',
I20161219-17:02:07.917(4)?         connection: 'close' },
I20161219-17:02:07.919(4)?      data: { error: [Object] } } }
I20161219-17:02:07.926(4)? res { statusCode: 401,
I20161219-17:02:07.926(4)?   content: '{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "required",\n    "message": "Login Required",\n    "locationType": "header",\n    "location": "Authorization"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 401,\n  "message": "Login Required"\n }\n}\n',
I20161219-17:02:07.926(4)?   headers: 
I20161219-17:02:07.928(4)?    { 'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UrTNWqenpV_aT_KKab8HA71eHYdc3t8pjIzo6e_JyW4OWz3fIopa6hVpCmDK5nTM0VE8z3UOam8bSNKQNatKjLHHN_zNPFLQl_9eet8VNXO-3yNBYU',
I20161219-17:02:07.928(4)?      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
I20161219-17:02:07.929(4)?      'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"',
I20161219-17:02:07.930(4)?      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
I20161219-17:02:07.931(4)?      'content-length': '238',
I20161219-17:02:07.931(4)?      date: 'Mon, 19 Dec 2016 13:02:07 GMT',
I20161219-17:02:07.932(4)?      server: 'UploadServer',
I20161219-17:02:07.933(4)?      'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"',
I20161219-17:02:07.933(4)?      connection: 'close' },
I20161219-17:02:07.933(4)?   data: { error: { errors: [Object], code: 401, message: 'Login Required' } } }
```

But I am signed in with my google account. Why am I getting this error?
I also tried to use atmosphere package GoogleApi but I get the same error. Please help dear sirs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem "Login Required".  You need to authenticate the user using Oauth2 first get an access token and apply the access token to your request.

Comment: I have the access token. But I am not sure if I apply it to my request. How do I do it? Simply just send it as another field in my json?

Comment: tack it on the end of any request like you would a get parm don't send it part of the post requests.  https:/   /www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token=thetoken

Comment: Now I get Error 400 bad request, Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. Maybe there is another way for sending the headers?